# Check if $W$ is a subspace of $P_n(\mathbb R)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> $W =  \{p \in P_n(\mathbb R) : p(2) = p(1)\}$

Is $W$ a subspace of $P_n(\mathbb R)$?

Note: $P_n(\mathbb R)$ denotes the vector space of all polynomials with degree $n$ or lower.

I am not sure how to check if it passes the Subspace Test since I can't quite understand how do I work with a n-degree polynomial.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a subspace since If $p, q \in W \Rightarrow p(1) = p(2), q(1) = q(2) \Rightarrow (p+q)(1) = p(1)+q(1) = p(2) + q(2) = (p+q)(2)\Rightarrow p+q \in W$, and for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, if $p \in W \Rightarrow \lambda\cdot p \in W$ since $(\lambda\cdot p)(1) = \lambda\cdot p(1) = \lambda\cdot p(2) = (\lambda\cdot p)(2)$